# Abstract Class and Concrete Subclasses

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass, concreteclass

I have two files: `Validador.java` and `Peca.java`. This is what I have in my Validador:

```
public class Validador {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 0) { 

             Peca p = new Rainha("t",1,2);

        }else if (args[0].equals("filtro")) { 

        }
    }
}
```

Peca:

```
public abstract class Peca {
    public static class Rainha extends Peca {
        Rainha(Tabuleiro tab, int linha, int coluna) {

        }
    }
    public static class Nada extends Peca {
        Nada(Tabuleiro tab, int linha, int coluna) {

        }
    }

}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Rainha cannot be resolved to a type

        at Validador.main(Validador.java:5)
```

How can I fix my Peca in order to be possible to call Rainha like this?

```
Peca p = new Rainha("t",1,2);
```

Thanks

Comment: The class is `Peca.Rainha`, not `Rainha`! And ... don't try to run code, that has compilation failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either import Peca.Rainha or write `Peca p = new Peca.Rainha("t",1,2);`

Comment: When I try that I get this error : The constructor Peca.Rainha(String, int, int) is undefined

Comment: @PEDROMIGUELCOSTA You've defined the constructor for that class as `Rainha(Tabuleiro tab, int linha, int coluna)` - you can't call it as `new Rainha("t",1,2)` - "t" is not a `Tabuleiro`, it's a string.

Comment: mannnn thanks so much! I was writing "t" instead of just t. Thanks a lot